# GPO unable to override a restricted group policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We have a global GPO that grants Local Admin permission to "Domain Users" via  Restricted Groups. I was asked to remove the Local Admin to few users by applying a security filter on their computers. All the approaches I tried didn't work. do you have any idea ?

Comment: So it's your intention to let every user to be the admin of every users machine?

Comment: Not mine, the decision was taken long time ago before my time.

Comment: I'd strongly urge you to bring up the security risk to mgmt.  Domain users as local admin means anyone at anytime has complete (potentially non-reputable) admin access to every client in the environment. If you want a complete list of why this is bad, you might ask over in the security stackexchange.

Comment: We actually have Bit9 deployed , it does a pretty good job filtering and preventing users from installing softwares , unless the software is in a whitelist. But I agree , local admin has to be removed .

Comment: so bit9 has a privilege higher than admin/system?

Answer (score 1):

Any GPO that target USER but got Computer setting must have the local loopback processing mode setting enabled.

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy

> **Merge** indicates that the user policies defined in the computer's Group Policy objects and the user policies normally applied to the
>   user are combined. If the policy settings conflict, the user policies
>   in the computer's Group Policy objects take precedence over the user's
>   normal policies.

Check the order of the GPO too, as of course both of your GPO apply to him (domain user + the gpo with him).

Comment: Actually the GPO is targeting Computers,
I enabled the loopback processing and enforced my GPO but didn't fix my issue.
My GPO applies but won't remove the Domain Users from the local administrators group.
I  just noticed that the main GPO has the Security Policy Processing enabled with option to  "Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed". any thought ?

Comment: @Nazim check the rsop then and the gpo order, as that gpo settings flush the other (its not merge, but replace). I mean, if two gpo for restricted group apply, the last one that apply win

Comment: @nazim Actually, i would isolate those pc in another OU to make only the settings you want to apply to them

Comment: I wanted to isolate them in a diffrent OU ,and copy the same main GPO without the Local Admin, but was told not to as we don't want a deep AD structure!

Comment: @nazim, try it, if it work you will have last word.